# Mouse clicks ignored by applications on 12.10 new install

Tags: mouse

I  am having issues with 12.10.

(I see the same issue posted here, but unsolved)

The mouse seems to work on some parts of Ubuntu and not others. for example, I can open apps (i.e. Chromium) using the left home bar thing, and if they are full-screen, with the button, I can navigate through folders, but if I open a web browser, I cannot click on anything in the browser, though I can use the keyboard and tab around. If the web browser is also not full screen, and the close/min/max buttons are on the top right, in black, I cannot use them.

when this is the case, the mouse is not at all frozen. I can move the cursor freely, open new apps, navigate through Ubuntu, only cannot click in any open apps with the mouse.

There is nothing wrong with the mouse, as it works great on Windows machines, and I have tried wired mircosoft mice to the same effect.

I had this problem after roughly 1 restart out of 5 when this was a Win7/Ubuntu 12.10 dual boot. Then a week ago, I redid partitions, deleted EVERYTHING, reinstalled Ubunt 12.10 and mouse clicks ignore problem resumed right away, again after roughly 1 restart out of 5.

My hardware: HP DV7 quad i5, 8MB RAM, 750 HDD, Microsoft wireless mouse and keyboard.
Ubuntu 12.10

Thanks, Rock.

Comment: It sounds like a driver problem. I'm not a driver pro, [but here's an MS wireless mouse installation guid](http://www.ehow.com/how_5844595_install-microsoft-wireless-mouse-ubuntu.html), I hope it will help you.

Comment: I notice that this only happens when I boot up and do not used the machine for a few minutes

Comment: Logging out and in again will fix it, at the expense of closing all open applications. I have same problem; specifically it happens if I leave my machine on for a long time and don't use it. I have overclocked it, but its a modest stable overclock. Basic logitech wired mouse. It has been occasionally crashing saying there is a problem with Ubuntu. The top-bar power symbol which lets you shut down responds fine to the mouse.