# cannot click in some windows, ubuntu 13.04 64bit

Tags: mouse, lightdm, gdm

EDIT: I tryed both, lightdm and gdm. ''sudo restart lightdm'' helps temporarly.

I cannot click in firefox until I start something else e.g. shell. 
But than the mouse cannot click anything outside the firefox window and keystrokes still go to the shell.

When I bring up the launcher with windows key I cannnot click the program icons, but I can select them with arrow keys.

When I try to start Catalyst Control Center an error message warns me that the mouse cannot be accessed and that there might be a virus.

Maybe related to this problem?
[Mouse clicks ignored by applications on 12.10 new install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278555/mouse-clicks-ignored-by-applications-on-12-10-new-install)